# Laravel - A model is not passed to first() method's closure

Tags: php, laravel, collections, model

I have a `collection` and I am calling `first()` method on it with a closure expecting a parameter say `$model`.

Upon execution, if I try to access a property of `$model`; it says:

> Accessing property of non-object

I tried dumping `$model` and found that it has a integer `1` instead of `Object`.

```
$Collection->first( function($model) {
    if(!$model) return false;
    return $model->type == 'Test';
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got it working. The `first()` method's argument closure is provided with 2 variables. First one is the key and second one is the model. So, you will call `first()` method like below and if it satisfies the criteria you defined, just return `true`.

```
$result = $collection->first( function($i, $model) {
    // define criteria and return true if it satisfies. The model will now be returned in resulting Collection.
});
```